# Xamarin.Forms Android - Clicking on dynamically Created Entry throws Exception in AndroidRuntime

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Description of what I'm trying to do**
I have a Stacklayout on my ContentPage. The user has an Add-Button. By clicking this Button my code is Generating a new Grid containing a Button to delete this Grid again, 3 entries and an Editor. This Grid is added to the Stacklayouts Children.

So far so good. Grid is Added to the Stacklayout. But when I click on an Entry with Android I get a Java.Lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, which I can't debug.

It's woriking fine on UWP. I don't know why it's not working on Android. The frustrating thing is that I can sometimes click on the Entry and nothing happens, but another time the App crashes with said Exceptopn

**XAML Snipped**

```
<Button Text="Add Newx:Name="AddNew" Clicked="AddNewButton_Clicked"/>
<StackLayout x:Name="MaterialStack" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" IsVisible="true" Spacing="15"/>
```

**How the Grid is Generated**

```
 public Grid CreateMaterialGrid()
    {
        
        Grid result = new Grid();            

        result.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        result.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        result.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        result.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star)
        };

        result.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
        result.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        Button deleteThisGridButton = new Button
        {
            Text = "Delete"
        };



        Entry materialEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Material"
        };          

        Entry fuhrenEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Fuhren",
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric
        };
        
        Entry tonnenEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Tonnen"
        };
     
     
        Editor lieferscheinNummernEditor = new Editor();
        lieferscheinNummernEditor.Placeholder = "Lieferscheinnummern";
        

        result.Children.Add(deleteThisGridButton, 0,0);
        result.Children.Add(materialEntry, 0, 1);
        result.Children.Add(fuhrenEntry, 0, 2);
        result.Children.Add(tonnenEntry, 0, 3);
        result.Children.Add(lieferscheinNummernEditor, 1, 1);

        Grid.SetRowSpan(lieferscheinNummernEditor, 3);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(deleteThisGridButton, 2);
                    

        return result;

    }
```

**Exception I get when clicking on an Entry**

```
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19; index=20
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2060)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:2107)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.widget.TextView.onProvideStructure(TextView.java:12712)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.View.onProvideAutofillStructure(View.java:9211)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.View.dispatchProvideStructure(View.java:10092)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.View.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(View.java:10085)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:4424)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:4424)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init>(AssistStructure.java:527)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init>(AssistStructure.java:2154)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3814)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2164)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
**Java.Lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:** 'length=19; index=20'
```

**What I have tried**

I tried to Localize the Problem and found it happens after the Focus Event of an Entry is finished.
 I tried to remove Entries to check if there is a Problem with one of them.
 I tried to remove EventListeners to check if the problem occours during one of them. 
 But no nothing worked. The Error is always the same exact one 
`Java.Lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:'length=19; index=20'`
 Length and Index are also always the same.
How can I solve the Problem of the App crashing when clicking on an Entry?

**I looked into this Error in the StackTrace**

```
at android.view.View.onProvideAutofillStructure
```

**Apparently there is an issue (on Samsung phones at least) with the Autofillfunction. I switched it from Samsung Pass to none. Afterwards no problems anymore in my App. Is there a way to turn off Autofill for my App? (Make the entries not use this feature)**

Comment: Focus on your test steps first. You can click to add and remove a GridView, no exception? But crash happens when clicking an entry? Any one of the entries would crash, or a particular one? What about the editor? Try to remove all the E_TextChanged or FocusedEntry event binding and test?

Comment: @Shaw Thanks for your reply. Yes i did this. I can add and remove grid views with no problem. It happens on every entry and also on the editor. Like I said not all the time, but most of the time. I also removed all my listeners to test. Still the same error

Comment: Your FocusedEntry method code missing? And I found Mr.19, which is your `lieferscheinNummernEditor.Placeholder = "Lieferscheinnummern";` and an exception could happen when you deal with this place holder

Comment: For simplicity, you can also try to add a StackLayout instead of a GridView and add the editor to it only (to eliminate the noise from GridView), keep the listener and test.

Comment: i had the same feeling when i found the Lieferscheinnummern. But i changed the lenght and also removed it. Nothing worked, still same error with same index numbers. The FocusedEntry Method is just a dummy method so i can have a breakpoint. nothing happens there. I wanted to find out when this exactly happens. I'm gonna try the idea with the StackLayout now. Thanks again

Comment: No. sadly the same Error. What's bugging me is that it doesn't happen in my Code but in Java and I can't see what string is processed. That would help so much. I also removed the `lieferscheinNummernEditor` completely now. Still not working.

Comment: have you stepped through the code to determine which specific line causes the exception?

Comment: @Jason I tried. But like I said the exception isn't caused by my code. It happens after the Focused Event. That's all i can say. I stepped through it and afterwards the exception is thrown, without another line of my code being executed. I'm thankful for any idea. That's also why I posted so much code, cause I don't know where to look anymore. Did I initialize something wrong? Did I put something in a place it shouldn't be?

Comment: There is nothing wrong posting code here, but as we cannot run the code directly, nor the specific line can be pointed out, better be [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), like using StackLayout, adding a static editor in code (remove the button), or leaving one entry only, so the issue can be found out more likely.

Comment: Thank your both for your input. Yesterday evening I found the solution to the problem. The Autofill function of the phone causes the problem. After turning it off in the settings there were no more problems. Is there a way to turn this function off programmatically for my app... or make the entries not use this feautre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Problem is with the Autofill service with Samsung. After turning it off the Exception didn't occur anymore

To turn it off go to Settings --> General Management --> Language and input --> Autofill service --> Autofill service --> Turn to None
[image]